# Ruby: Detect times when Fedora machine is powered-on

Tags: ruby, linux, fedora, uptime

feels like I visited stackoverflow 100 times before. Always found good solutions, but now I'm stuck.

I want to monitor how long a computer runs every day. This is part of a program written in Ruby, running on a Fedora machine.

Previously I did similar things under Windows, where it is possible to catch the related power events using WndProc. However, with Fedora (or Linux in general) I don't find a good hook to detect power-on and power-off/suspend/hibernate/....

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
jayrock

EDIT: Seems I haven't been clear in what I want to achieve. Actually want to have information about not only the current uptime but also past uptimes. Thus I should know "the computer has been running for x hours over the last 14 days" or similar.

Another addition is that e.g. the `last` command doesn't do the job either - it doesn't show if the system goes to hibernate or suspend.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to parse the output from the `last` command, which logs users' logins. If the pseudo-user `reboot` "logged in", you know the system was rebooted. (This is valid for Ubuntu; maybe Fedora uses a different name, such as `boot`.)

There may be a more direct interface; Google around for `ruby + utmp`. The `utmp` file, commonly in `/var/run`, records the data that the `last` command reports.

Comment: The last command unfortunately doesn't work for my purpose, because it doesn't log when the system goes to sleep.

Comment: @jayrock: `last` also displays how long a user has been logged in, in the last column. For `reboot`, that would equal system uptime.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this does it. Let me do some more testing.

Comment: Tested this extensively now. Turns out that indeed reboot stays logged on when the system goes to suspend or hibernation. So unfortunately I still don't have a good solution. For instance I get this line `reboot   system boot  2.6.35.10-74.fc1 Wed Feb 16 20:00 - 08:36  (12:36)` - but for sure the system was on standby during the night.

Comment: @jayrock: Too bad. Maybe you can try writing a "proxy program" for APMD in Ruby? See http://linux.die.net/man/8/apmd

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the ruby specifics but there is a command uptime in linux.

I think in ruby you need to use System

so it would be something like `system 'uptime'`

Then you can parse the results of that

Answer (score 0):

You would use backticks like `uptime`
StackOverflow regards them as code styles though in this answer box.